How to get new Forms experience for "Add New Item" in a list?
I have a SharePoint Online collaboration site with a custom list for a service request. I've used the Forms option to create an input form for my list. My problem is that I can't find an intuitive way for users on the list page to create a new item with the custom form.
I see that I can get a link to the form to provide to users to fill it out, but most of them will be accessing it from the list view on the SPO site, so the way they're used to creating new items is to click on the Add New Item button:

However, when they do that, they get the generic add item input form:

When they're creating a new item, though, I want them to see the custom form with the field explanations:

Ideally, I'd like the edit item function to also use the custom form, but even getting the create function to use it for now would be a win.
Our environment is quite locked-down, so I can't use Power Automate or run a PowerShell script to modify anything. It seems pretty pointless having a custom form that can't easily be accessed from the list it's feeding into... am I missing something?

so you just want to display field description for each field in the form? If Yes, you can do that by adding description for each field from the list settings. And then your description text you added for each field will appear in your default list forms.

You can add description for each field in the List and these text will appear in your list default forms.
Steps:

Go to your list settings.
Click on each field to add your description text and save the changes.

Do the above steps for all fields.
Go to your form. That description text will appear in your new form below the each field.



Thanks for both the initial answer and the step-by-step. The format isn't quite as pleasant as the new form view, but this achieves my objective of making the description field visible for each column.

To add description to columns, you could use the new feature in the SharePoint list.
1.Click Forms in the ribbon.

2.Click the column to add description.

3.Click Send form -> Copy link.

Result for users:

